# Create non root user in Docker Alpine images with lesser image size?

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux

I am using docker node `node:alpine` for building the container but i would like to start my node application as non root user.
Just adding the user and group using `adduser` and `addgroup` is increasing the size of image by 300MB compared to when running as root user.

Using `shadow` from alpine testing repo also does the same (i.e. increases the size of my image by 300MB).
RUN echo http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories

Any tools or any suggestions how to create non root user with considerably not increasing the size of image too much ?

Comment: Can you provide the full docker file.

Comment: Running adduser or addgroup doesn't affect sizes. Running chown and chmod does

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to switch the storage driver from aufs to device mapper as described [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/6119#issuecomment-268870519).

Alternatively, another solution is to directly copy the resources from the host and set the owner in the same `COPY` instruction

```
COPY [--chown=<user>:<group>] <src>... <dest>
```

Comment: thank you for the link. Using `--chown` flag along with `COPY` or `ADD` command solves the issue and the image size would be as origninal.

Answer (score 2):

Since I can't comment, please by all means ignore the answer of Sergey Yarotskiy. This is a dangerous misleading answer, which is also wrong.

Read for example https://medium.com/@mccode/processes-in-containers-should-not-run-as-root-2feae3f0df3b to why you should NEVER run as root in your containers unless you really explicitly need to.

However you can instead run your container with docker run -u to specify the user manually.